# Why does web form return fields to Python CGI as MiniFieldStorage?

Tags: python, web, cgi

I am trying to get user-inputted data from a web page generated in one Python script to submit to another Python script to process that data.  In the first python script I have used the following to create a web form to submit data:

```
print("<form action='newspeciescheck.py' method='post'>")
print("<p>Genus: <input  type='text' name='newgenus'/> <p>Species: <input type='text' name='newspecies'/>")
print("<input type='submit' value='Enter'>")
print("</form>\n ")
```

In the target script I have

```
formfields = cgi.FieldStorage()
newgenus = formfields.getValue('newgenus')
newspecies = formfields.getValue('newspecies')
```

However, when I try to run this, cgitb throws an error telling me that:

```
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.


C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\pyscripts\newspeciescheck.py in ()
     21 
     22 formfields = cgi.FieldStorage()
=>   23 newgenus = formfields.getValue('newgenus')
     24 status=''
     25 if newgenus==None:
newgenus undefined, formfields = FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('newg...phis'), MiniFieldStorage('newspecies', 'fabae')]), formfields.getValue undefined
 C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\cgi.py in __getattr__(self=FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('newg...phis'), MiniFieldStorage('newspecies', 'fabae')]), name='getValue')
    583     def __getattr__(self, name):
    584         if name != 'value':
=>  585             raise AttributeError(name)
    586         if self.file:
    587             self.file.seek(0)
builtin AttributeError = <class 'AttributeError'>, name = 'getValue'
AttributeError: getValue 
      args = ('getValue',) 
      with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of AttributeError object>
```

So why do my submitted values end up in MiniFieldStorage rather than normal FieldStorage? More importantly how do I get them to end up as normal FieldStorage?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to include a clear problem description. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing the error because you are trying to access `FieldStorage`'s `getValue` method, it doesn't have one - the correct method name is `getvalue` - note the lowercase v.

However, this is the answer to your question about `FieldStorage` vs `MiniFieldStorage`

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/cgi.html#using-the-cgi-module), whether values end up as `FieldStorage` or `MiniFieldStorage` instances depends on the encoding type (the `enctype` attribute) of the form used to submit them.

> The file upload draft standard entertains the possibility of uploading
>   multiple files from one field (using a recursive multipart/*
>   encoding). When this occurs, the item will be a dictionary-like
>   FieldStorage item. This can be determined by testing its type
>   attribute, which should be multipart/form-data (or perhaps another
>   MIME type matching multipart/*). In this case, it can be iterated over
>   recursively just like the top-level form object.
>
> When a form is submitted in the “old” format (as the query string or
>   as a single data part of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded), the
>   items will actually be instances of the class MiniFieldStorage.

The [default encoding type](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-enctype) is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` So if you want to force the use of `FieldStorage`, your form declaration needs to be

```
<form action='newspeciescheck.py' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data) for a discussion of form encodings, and why you might select one or the other.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful.